# Laravel Blade Using custom function

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a blade where I'm printing the content of a table.
For some columns I need to add the CSS class according the value I'm printing.

E.g. if it's "OK", add class Green, otherwise class red.
Of course the logic will be more complex, but the point is that all the logic will be related to the style.

Which one is the best recommended place to save this type of function/method?
Do I need to create a Model?

** UPDATE **

```
            <thead>                                     
                <tr>                   
                    <th> ID </th>
                    <th> Name </th>
                    <th> Last Checked </th>
                    <th> Status </th>                    
                </tr>                                                   
            </thead>                                                    
            <tbody>     
                @foreach ($users as $u)
                    <tr>               
                        <td> {{ $u->id }}</td>
                        <td> {{ $u->name }}</td>
                        <td> {{ $u->last_login }}</td>
                        <td> {!! statusWrapper( $u->status ) !!}</td>
                    </tr>              
                @endforeach                                                      
            </tbody>                                                                         
        </table>
```

"statusWrapper" is the function that I'd like to call to decorate the Status value.
So the status is a number, and the output will be something like `<span class="..."> .... </span>`

Comment: If it's simple logic, put it in your view?

Comment: Why need model? Its very simple. Share your some code that you have  implemented.

Comment: @ProEvilz, What if the logic is a bit more complex or it can be something I can share with more then one view?

Comment: @MahfuzShishir, I've updated the question with a code example

Answer (score 3):

If status should include HTML like showing different colors I recommend you use @include

```
// resources/views/statusWrapper
@if($status == 'good')
    <span style="color: green;">thats really good</span>
@else
    <span style="color: red;">not good</span>
@endif
```

and then in your table view

```
@foreach ($users as $u)
<tr>               
   <td> {{ $u->id }}</td>
   <td> {{ $u->name }}</td>
   <td> {{ $u->last_login }}</td>
   <td>
       @include('statusWrapper', ['status' => $u->status])
   </td>
</tr>              
@endforeach
```

You could also look at extending blade: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#extending-blade

But I will not recommend you to put HTML in your PHP code as it's easier to keep your HTML in your view files for future edits.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you what I always do myself. You don't need to make a model, you just have to make a helper file and write all your custom functions in it. For example you can make a file named helper.php in **app/Http/Helpers/** path. Then you have to make your project aware of this file. To do that you just have to add it in your composer.json file in autoload -> files object like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "files":[

        "app/Http/Helpers/helper.php"
    ]
}
```

After this just run command **composer dump-autoload**. Now you can access to your custom functions which are in you helper.php file from anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

If you're planning to use the function in multiple blade templates, then [Tohid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526564/3852890) is the best.

If you just need the function in a single template, you can define it directly in the `.blade.php` file like this:

```
@php
if ( !function_exists( 'mytemplatefunction' ) ) {
   function mytemplatefunction( $param ) {
      return $param . " World";
   }
 }
 @endphp
```

Then in you can call the function from within the same template:

```
<p>{{ mytemplatefunction("Hello") }}</p>
```

The conditional function definition is needed if you include the blade template multiple times in the same session.

Answer (score 2):

**app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php (You can create a different Service Provider, if you wish)**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;

...

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    ...


    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('statusWrapper', function ($status) {
            return "<?php echo App\ViewComponents\StatusWrapperComponent::statusWrapper( $status ); ?>"; 
        });
    }
}
```

**app/ViewComponents/StatusWrapperComponent.php**

```
namespace App\ViewComponents;

class StatusWrapperComponent {

    public static function statusWrapper ($status) {
        if($status == 'good')
            echo '<span style="color: green;">thats really good</span>';
        else
            echo '<span style="color: red;">not good</span>';
    }

}
```

**resources/views/yourview.blade.php**

```
<thead>                                     
                <tr>                   
                    <th> ID </th>
                    <th> Name </th>
                    <th> Last Checked </th>
                    <th> Status </th>                    
                </tr>                                                   
            </thead>                                                    
            <tbody>     
                @foreach ($users as $u)
                    <tr>               
                        <td> {{ $u->id }}</td>
                        <td> {{ $u->name }}</td>
                        <td> {{ $u->last_login }}</td>
                        <td> @statusWrapper($u->status) </td>
                    </tr>              
                @endforeach                                                      
            </tbody>                                                                         
        </table>
```