# Laravel table cell color with cell value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is my blade loop.

```
@for ($coun=0;$coun< $count_2; $coun++)
<table id="table2" border="1" style="display: inline-block;clear: both;">
        <tbody>
          <tr><td><?php print_r( $array_mem['id'][$coun]); ?></td></tr>
          <tr><td><?php print_r( $array_mem['Name'][$coun]); ?></td></tr>
          <tr><td><?php print_r( $array_mem['Mark'][$coun]); ?></td></tr>
          <tr><td><?php print_r( $array_mem['Sub_1'][$coun]); ?></td></tr>
          <tr><td><?php print_r( $array_mem['Sub_2'][$coun]); ?></td></tr>
          <tr><td><?php print_r( $array_mem['Sub_3'][$coun]); ?></td></tr>
        </tbody>
</table> @endfor
```

I Have set of conditions to check the values in each column. and also change the cell colour depends.

```
+-------------------+-------------+
| Condition         | Cell Colour |
+-------------------+-------------+
| If Id < 10        | Red         |
+-------------------+-------------+
| If Id>10 && Id<20 | Green       |
+-------------------+-------------+
| If Mark <20       | Red         |
+-------------------+-------------+
| If Mark >20       | Green       |
+-------------------+-------------+
| If Sub_1 < 20     | Red         |
+-------------------+-------------+
```

Is there any way to check and make the cell in specific colour.

Am looking something except using if else condition,  that means using **function** or **this**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Blade Using custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46524620/laravel-blade-using-custom-function)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a mutator from your `model` class and add all of your logic in

```
public function getCellColorAttribute(){
  $cellColor = "";
  if($this->id > 10 || $this->mark < 20 || $this->sub_1 < 20 ) 
        $cellColor = 'red';
  else 
        $cellColor = 'green';

  return $cellColor;
}
```

now when you iterate this model in your `view` you can access this new attribute with `cell_color`

you can read more about **Accessors & Mutators** [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: How to call this in blade. I am not proficient in  Laravel

Comment: could you add your controller method ? in your question?

Comment: Route::get('/search-panel', UploadPanelController@search_index');

Comment: add you controller in your case it is called `UploadPanelController` i think

Comment: yes controller is UploadPanelController , function is search_index

Comment: public  function search_index()
    {
        return view ('admin.upload-panel.search-panel');
    }

Comment: where is the data you pass in this view ?? there is no data

Answer (score 1):

You should extract the logic somewhere else instead of doing if/else in the view and you can do it in many ways. One approach could be creating a helper file and declaring a helper function and use it in view. So, to do that, you can create a helper file in `app/Helpers/Helper.php`, then in your `composer.json` file you can add an entry in `files` section like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/Helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Then in your `"app/Helpers/Helpers.php"` file add a function, for example:

```
if (!function_exists('getCellColor')) {
    function getCellColor($arg) {
        $cellColor = '';

        // Implement your login verifying the $arg...

        return $cellColor;
    }
}
```

Then you should run `composer dump-autoload` from your `terminal/command prompt`. Now you can use that function in the place where you need the formatting. For example:

```
<tr><td style="color: {{ getCellColor($array_mem) }}"></td></tr>
```

In this case, you can return something like this from the function:

```
// ...

$cellColor = '';

// Verify and set the color...

$cellColor = 'red';

return $cellColor;
```

Alternatively, you can use/return a `class` like:

```
$cellColorClass = 'red';

// assign the right color class...

return $cellColorClass;
```

You may use it like:

```
<tr><td class="{{ getCellColor($array_mem) }}"></td></tr>
```

In that case, you need to create some `css` rules in a new or existing `css` file like:

```
.red {
    color: red;
}

.green {
    color: green;
}
```

That's it. This is one approach among many, so take the idea and use what you think is better for you but this one is easy, IMO.